# Verifying is an array is a subset of another

Tags: c++, arrays, subset

This is a popular question, but I can't find an answer that satisfies my case.

I have arrays of booleans, in which I'm trying to see if one array is a subset of another.

example:

```
const int size = 10;
bool arr1[size];
bool arr2[size];
bool arr3[size];

assume the arrays have been initialized to false except for the following:

arr1 4,5,6 = true
arr2 0 = true
arr3 4,5 = true
```

in this example, `arr2` is not a subset of either, but `arr3` is a subset of `arr1`.

I have tried some messy attempts of creating an array of integers from the true values of bools, but I still am not sure how to verify that they are in sequence (i.e a subset) of one another.

I attempted to use this algorithm

```
int size = 10;
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<size; j++)
    {
       if(arr2[i] == arr1[j])
          break;
    }
    if (j == size)
       return false;
}
return true;
}
```

This one didn't work either.

The objective is to determine if one array contains all the elements of another.
In this case, `arr3` has indexes 4 and 5 as true, which is also true in `arr1`

but if I compare `arr2` to the superset `arr1`, it will return false because `arr1[0]` is not true.

Comment: Uninitialized values **and** accessing arrays out of bounds -> two reasons for *undefined behavior*

Comment: Utilize [std::includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes).

Comment: you seem to have some special understanding of what a "subset" is. Strictly speaking if two sets have same number of elements, then one can only be subset of the other if they contain exactly the same elements. (Actually, strictly speaking a set contains no element twice)

Comment: Since, you don't assign any values to `arr1` elements indexed 0-3, 7-9, `arr2` elements indexed 1-9, and `arr3` elements indexed 0-4, 7-9, iterating through the list and checking each and every value is meaningless - since those elements will have indeterminate values.

Comment: Look up logical ops. AND both arrays, call them a and b, and then compare the result for equality to b. If true, b is a subset of a (your terminology).

Comment: Assume the arrays have been initialized.

I'm trying to not copy and paste a class and a bunch of member functions so this is just a placeholder example.

Comment: posting an example is no excuse for having bugs that arent related to your original problem. Eg please fix `const int size = 10;` vs `int size = 256`.  See also [mcve].

Comment: fair enough @tobi303 
fixed.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "subset" since the standard definition doesn't fit. There are exactly 4 different sets with Boolean elements so there's no problem in finding all (standard) subsets of those.

Comment: Still trying understand what you want to do: You want to know if all indices that are true in one array are also true in a second array? If so, your algorithm is overly complicated and wrong. You would need a single loop that `if (arr1[i] == true)` checks if also `arr2[i] == true`

Comment: forgive me for being ambiguous.

What I mean to say is that if all the values of `arr2` are in `arr1` then it should return true.

Comment: @Ozymandias my guess is that you are mixing the arrays with what they represent in your code (something that we cannot know). To be clear: the values in an array of `bool` are either `true` or `false` and there are only three cases of what elements such array can contain: only `true`, only `false`, or both, but as you are juggling with indices I am pretty sure that you do not simply want to know "if all the values of arr2 are in arr1"

Comment: @tobi303 They are indeed arrays of bools, containing true or false.

and I only want to know if all the same true values of `arr2` are in `arr1`.

Comment: To my understanding you want to know if the set of indices where `arr1[i] == true` is a subset of the set of indices where `arr2[i] == true`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes!

The guy that wrote in the algorithm below provided exactly what I was asking.

my apologies for the poorly written explanations, I didn't know how to better describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the function to check if array `a` has all the indexes `true` that are `true` in `b` or not, here `a` and `b` are of the same size.

```
bool checkArrays(bool a[], bool b[], int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(b[i] && b[i] != a[i]) // compare only if b[i] is true
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking for!

Thank you kindly.